# Sudden loss of DB connection in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, localhost, mamp

I was going to work on a PHP project I regularly work on, but I've encountered a strange error I can't seem to fix.

In my project, I connect to a MySQL database using MySqli name "cms". I've been regularly using this connection, but suddenly errors are being thrown about it not existing.

Here's the error:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (42000/1049): Unknown database 'cms' in    
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\School\Dal\2017-2018 Winter\INFX2670 - Serverside 
Scripting\assignments\A5\includes\header.php on line 13
```

I've ensured the database still exists, as shown in a screenshot I took from phpMyAdmin

[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voXzd.png)

And the code triggering this error:

```
//basic connection variables
$host = "localhost:3307";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "cms";

//connect to db
$conn = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);
```

This code has always worked, and suddenly threw this error when I woke up this morning. I'm using MAMP to do localhost, and the only suspicious thing I could find is when starting MAMP this morning, the port had changed to 3306. This port is taken by MySQL workbench so I usually have it on 3307 and it works fine. It's currently on 3307.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!